# Automating xcode update

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sikuli

I have 1 app built in xcode for iPhone and iPad which is altered slightly differently for different companies but it is the same base app exactly except for the name, certain colour settings, website link and databased referenced too along with customers custom graphics.

When we have to do an update to the build I have to update the same app around 200 times now only changing an if statement to point towards a certain companies version, the identifier, name and graphics and it's extremely repetitive and I'm wondering if there would be anyway to go about building a script to automate this.

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode command-line tools installs a utility called `xcodebuild` that you use in scripts. Facebook's [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) is worth taking a look at too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should make a config file with compiler directives in it. Define constants in the target and then write out something like this:

```
#ifdef TARGET1
#define PRIMARY_BACKGROUND [UIColor whiteColor]
#define WEB_SERVICE @"http://www.targert1.com/services"
#endif

#ifdef TARGET2
#define PRIMARY_BACKGROUND [UIColor blackColor]
#define WEB_SERVICE @"http://www.targert2.com/services"
#endif
```